# Every subclass in Java inherits from two classes (Object and its superclass)?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

When I create a new class, it is

```
ClassA extends Object{
}
```

So, if I were to have ClassA inherit from ClassB, wouldn't it be

```
ClassA extends Object extends ClassB {
}
```

which is basically Multiple Inheritance that is not allowed in Java.

Or is there a special exception for the Object class, which means it is indeed, safe to say, that **every base class in Java inherits from exactly 2 classes** ?

Comment: Multiple inheritance is having two direct super classes. Instead this is a class hierarchy where `B` extends `A`, which in turn extends `Object`.

Comment: The only special exception for `Object` is: "The extends clause must not appear in the definition of the class Object, or a compile-time error occurs, because it is the primordial class and has no direct superclass." (From [JLS Sec 8.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

It would be ClassA inherits from ClassB which inherits from Object.

This is not multiple inheritance. This is single inheritance. Single inheritance gives you sort of a chain:

```
Object -> ClassB -> ClassA
```

Multiple inheritance lets you do more of a tree:

```
Object -> ClassB \
                  ---> ClassA
Object -> ClassC /
```

Java doesn't let you do the latter. The closest you can get is implementing multiple interfaces.

Note that this is still OK (single inheritance), since each class has at most one direct base:

```
                  /--> ClassC
Object -> ClassB -
                  \--> ClassD
```

Also, to answer your direct question, [JLS 8.1.4 states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4) (emphasis mine):

> Given a ... class declaration ... the direct superclass of the class type C ... is **the type given in the extends clause of the declaration of C if an extends clause is present, or Object otherwise.**

That is, it's still single inheritance. If you have an `extends` then that's the base class, otherwise the base is `Object`. In your example, `ClassA` **does not have `Object` as a direct base**.

---

You can experiment for yourself a little, too. [Check out this example](http://ideone.com/xfspUe):

```
static class ClassB {
}

static class ClassA extends ClassB {
}

static void printHierarchy (Class<?> clz) {
    if (clz != null) {
        System.out.println(clz.getSimpleName());
        System.out.print("inherits from: ");
        printHierarchy(clz.getSuperclass());
    } else {
        System.out.println("nothing");
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    printHierarchy(ClassA.class);
}
```

Outputs:

```
ClassA
inherits from: ClassB
inherits from: Object
inherits from: nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support Multiple Inheritance. Instead what you are describing is a class heirarchy. All classes in Java that do not explicitly extend a class, extend `Object`. However, if a class `A` extends `B`, then it is not directly extending `Object`. Because `B` directly extends `Object`, `A` is still a child class of `Object` (as in you can do `Object a = new A()` without any problems), but it is not a direct subclass.

Comment: @Andreas I did not intend to. I'll edit my answer. Thank you.